# Prism Forms - can not see NavigationBar

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Xamarin.Forms: 3.0.0.550

Prism: 7.0.0.396

Here is my code snippet in App.xaml.cs :

```html
protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/CoursesPage");
        }

protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CoursesPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Content>();
        }
```

After running I do not see NavigationBar on CoursesPage even if is set NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True" in xaml file.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: What are you not seeing? Do you see the title of the page? If so it seems everything is correct, because you navigate to the Courses page directly meaning this is the first page shown - thus no back arrow should be drawn!

Comment: Sorry, my CoursesPage has the title and NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True" and I still do not see NavigationBar with title inside and wihout back button.

Comment: If you did not change the sample you supplied above, this is normal. The first page shown in an app never has a backbutton in the NavigationBar. You first have to navigate to a second page...

Comment: I understand this. I do not want to have back button. I just want to see navigationBar with my title inside.

Comment: Ok, I see... well the page itself has the Title property filled in? Because to be honest with only the code we see here, everything looks fine.

Comment: <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             x:Class="MiniRozmowkiApp.Views.CoursesPage">
    <Label Text="CoursesPage"/>
</ContentPage>

Comment: public class CoursesPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public CoursesPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "COURSES";
        }
 }

Comment: That is why I am asking. Is anyone can confirm such bug in new Pirsm version? Or maybe I have something wrong.

Comment: I just want to add that my project was created with Prism Template Pack 2.0.9. Maybe here we have some problem.

Comment: Could... because I just recreated your scenario and it works.

Comment: Ok, I have created new test project and it works fine. Thx for help.

Comment: Did you change anything else in your new sample? Because i've the same problem, but only on ios, on UWP everything is fine. It's a large project, so setting it up again would be a large effort.